# How to change domain name with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I have two domains that is

```
1. learnhowto.com
2. lht.com
```

When a user visits **`lht.com/er45c`** it should automatically redirected to **`learnhowto.com/er45c`** 
How do i do it with .htaccess

My current htaccess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lht.com/$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.lht.com/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://learnhowto.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this in an .htaccess file rather than directly in the Apache configuration file?

Comment: @anubhava I think it is a bit unclear what you are saying.

Comment: I changed the position but nothing changed

Comment: Can you show `VirtualHost` entries of both domains? Are they pointing to same directory on same host?

Comment: `lht.com/` is _not_ a host name, but `lht.com` is...